# Better to recreate listview adapter or to clear and repopulate?

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

If I have a `ListView` with a `CustomAdapter` and let's say I have this `refresh()` method that refreshes the list with new results, should I:

1. Call `new CustomAdapter(...)` upon initialization, and every time I call `refresh()`, I use `adapter.clear()` and `adapter.add(...)`
2. Call `new CustomAdapter(...)` every time I call `refresh()`

Basically, I'm asking, is it better to recreate an adapter everytime I load new results or is it better to clear the results in existing adapter and add the entire list to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It is definitely better to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the original adapter than setting a new one.**

The reason is performance: `ListView` uses view recycling to avoid creating new item views as you scroll. When you set a new adapter, these recycled views are discarded, which means they must be recreated from scratch for the next layout pass. Take a look at the [code of `ListView.setAdapter()`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ListView.java):

```
@Override
public void setAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
    if (mAdapter != null && mDataSetObserver != null) {
        mAdapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(mDataSetObserver);
    }

    resetList();
    mRecycler.clear();

    ...
```

This is completely logical behavior, since the `ListView` supposes that the views the new adapter will use are incompatible with the ones returned by the previous adapter (in any case, it cannot *assume* that they will be compatible). So they're thrown away.

Therefore, if you set a new adapter each time, you're incurring an unnecessary performance cost (recreating all the current views).

Also, if you wrote a *custom* adapter, you don't necessarily have to call `add()` individually (as with, say, `ArrayAdapter`). You can just replace the internal data collection with the new one and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

I think if you're going to use adapters as they were intended, then you'll update the adapter's data and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on it.

If you look at the API for something like [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html), it has numerous methods like `clear()`, `add()`, `addAll()`, `notifyDataSetChanged()` and so forth that are there to guide you towards a certain use of the API.

By using these methods, not only does it make your code compliant with its intended usage, it also makes it easier to understand and familiar to others that are trying to understand your code.

So basically, I would only recreate the adapter as a last resort.

Comment: But I think using `add()` is much slower (not proven yet). Passing the data list as an argument in its constructor actually speeds up the process (personal experience). So I really don't know...

Comment: But after you create the new adapter, you have to call ListView#setAdapter() which has its own overhead: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ListView.java